# Why does the address of the first element in 'std::string' print out as the whole string?

Tags: c++

Let's say that a string has a value of "Test string". I tried printing out &string[0] and what I got is the same thing but what I expected was a 'T'. When I tried printing out &string[1] I got "est string". Can someone explain why does it work this way?

Comment: Have a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at

Comment: Let say you read [ask] and post a [mcve] ;) Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`string[0]` returns the first character from the string.
`&string[0]` is the address of this first character, of type `char*`, so when you pass that to `std::cout` or `printf()` (with %s), it will print the whole string up to the terminating \0 character.

The same applies of course to `string[1]` etc.

Edit:
But, as Daniel correctly pointed out, before C++ 11 this behaviour was not guaranteed. You should use `std::string::c_str()` in this case.

Comment: True, but to be pedantic this behavior is only standardized since C++11. Before there was no official guarantee that the string would be stored in contiguous memory, as expected by functions working with C strings.

Comment: You're right. But, as you put it, there was no 'official guarantee', but I assume that most implementations worked that way already.